# No abre modal en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

yo antes tenia mi código organizado así.

Parte de mi index.php

```
<!-- barra de navegacion -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                  <i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <a href="index.html"><img src="img utiles/socialprop5.png" width="60px"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-collapse collapse">
                  <li><a href="faq/faq.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> F.A.Q</a></li>
                  <li><a href="login.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user_login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" ></span>Accede</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="register.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user_register"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" id="register"></span> Registrate</a></li>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      <!--COMIENZO MODAL LOGIN-->
        <div id="user_login" class="modal fade"  role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
              <!-- FIN MODAL LOGIN -->
```

Login.php

```
    <div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  <h2 class="modal-title" style="display:block">Iniciar Sesion</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

  <!-- MODAL BODY LOGIN -->
  <div id="user_login">
    <form action="Principal/principal.php" id="loginForm" class='form-vertical' method="POST">
          <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook">
          Iniciar sesion con Facebook
          <i class="fa fa-facebook" id='redessociales' aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

          <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google">
          Iniciar sesion con Google
          <i class="fa fa-google" id='redessociales' aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </a>
                    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email</label>
          <input type="text" name="mail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" autofocus="" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Contraseña</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña">
                    </div>

        <div class="Checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="recuerdame">Recuerdame
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Enviar" id="botonLogin" >Iniciar Sesion</button>
        </div>
        <a href="misspass.php" data-target="#user_recovery"data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal">Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>
      </form>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" href="register.php" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user_register">Registrate!</button>
        <button type="cerrar" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

navbar de laravel(fijarse en login)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto funcionaba perfectamente.
Con laravel no entiendo como routear al modal para que siga en la vista index y se abra aqui.
Tendria que routear a loginmodal.blade.php(ignoren los otros son pruebas fallidas)
[image: Route y Blade]

Comment: Otra como se me ocurria es tener un modal.blade.php que extienda a modallogin y modalregister usando section y yield etc. Pero como ni siquiera puedo hacerlo andar como antes, ni me gasto

Comment: La verdad no entiendo cual es el problema. ¿qué es lo que no funciona y cómo debería funcionar?

Comment: Que el route no routea al blade, entonces no levanta el modal en laravel. En mi version PHP si andaba todo. Con laravel no entiendo como poner las rutas

Comment: ¿cuál ruta no funciona? ¿Ninguna?

Comment: La ruta para que levante el modallogin.blade.php. No entiendo como poner

Comment: No entiendo el contexto de la palabra "levantar", si entiendo bien no te funciona la ruta /login? Según el archivo de rutas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48427/discussion-between-hernan-bessera-and-shaz).

Answer (score 1):

Conceptualmente no puedes crear una ruta que apunte a un modal. El modal es un componente 100% de Front End. Lo que significa que no podemos interactuar desde el server con éste componente.

Lo que sí puedes hacer es crear una ruta hacia una vista o pantalla .php
Luego, dentro de esa pantalla puedes tener tu modal, y si todo lo que tienes en esa vista es el modal pues puedes levantar la modal en el momento en que todo el DOM esté listo.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#user_login").modal("show");
});
```